# Authenticate user through Azure AD from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm very sorry to ask such a broad question, but I haven't found any direct answer when I and colleagues have searched the internet.

We have AWS Lambdas that needs to authenticate and authorize from an Azure AD.
How do we accomplish this?

I understand that the question is very broad and hard to answer, but if someone knows of a good guide or some step by step instructions that can help me get going I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: The pattern I am contemplating is SPA application, API Gateway and Lambda Authorizers.  A Lambda authorizer (formerly known as a custom authorizer) is an API Gateway feature that uses a Lambda function to control access to your API.

A Lambda authorizer is useful if you want to implement a custom authorization scheme that uses a bearer token authentication strategy such as OAuth or SAML, or that uses request parameters to determine the caller's identity.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget the "AWS Lambda" part. Consider it as external app that needs to get token from Azure AD in order to have it's requests authorized. You can achieve this using Azure AD REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offer the Active Directory Authentication Library.  Information on ADAL can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries

In terms of identity and access management, you have a few options but I would recommend the use of **Azure Service Principals**.  More information can be found:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals

If you're not familiar with Azure AD, or OAuth, and are inquisitive enough, you should really start at the beginning:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/

The docs are written plainly and very well, in my opinion.